# Error using Mask_RCNN with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-recognition

I m quite new to tensorflow, but after some time spent on it, i tried to train a model with Mask_rcnn with my own images to make an object recognition. I use jupyter notebooks. In the training block I found an error which I cannot overcome.

***OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.***

I attach a picture to show the chain that bring to the error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGm0Y.jpg)

I hope someone will help me! 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which version of Tensorflow and which implementation of Mask-RCNN do you use?   Also please provide code to reproduce the error.

Comment: I m using: tensorflow 1.3.0, python 3.6.9, tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1.

Comment: I m using the train_mask_rcnn